# How to prevent files settings xml file from being downloaded by entering url but allow php to see

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have an xml file on the server containing details to the database server. I don't want anyone to be able to access it via url but PHP should be able to load the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

- Simple move all those kinds of files outside the webroot, for example /application instead of /public_html/myapplication. You only need accessible pages (index.php etc.) inside the webroot.
- Or if that's not possible/too hard, add this in `.htaccess` in the folder that contains the XML file (but it cannot contain files that should be accessible)

.

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use .htaccess file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html
but, why put it in XML? put it in PHP as variables, then even if they visit the page they won't be able to see it.